# BehaviorSubject Issue

Tags: angular

Well, everything works fine but not as I expected. I'm trying to get the current value from component A when the user saves an image, and share that img through a service ( using a `BehaviorSubject` ) and store it in component B. I know that I always get the current value, but my intention is to store that last value and save all images that I want, not just overriding the current value with the last one.

Current Issue:  I always store JUST the last image.
 What I expect: Store all images

I tried to use Subject, ReplaySubject(1) instead of BehaviorSubject just to not initialize the value, or BehaviorSubject with skip operator to get the last value. I don't really know what I'm missing. Also, I removed `ngOnDestroy()` just to know if I was destroying the whole variable, although that doesn't make sense because I store it after getting the value.

// image-state.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ImageStateService {


  private imgStateSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  imageState$ = this.imgStateSubject.asObservable();

  constructor() {
   }

   getImage(val: string) {
    this.imgStateSubject.next(val);
   }
}
```

// Emmitted value from component A

```
 onSave(severity: string, data: string) {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: 'Are you sure that you want to save it in Gallery?',
      accept: () => {
        this.imageStateService.getImage(data); // Getting the value
        this.messageService.add({ severity: severity, summary: 'Success', detail: 'Data Saved' });
      }
    });
  }
```

// Recieving value ( Component B )

```
images: Image[];
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private imageStateService: ImageStateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.images = [];
    this.subscription = this.imageStateService.imageState$
      .subscribe(val => this.images.push
        ({source: `${val}`, alt: 'Description for Image 1', title: 'Title 1'}));

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't see the point of using subject here if you want all images, why not just use an ordinary array?

Comment: i'd have to use something like @output, but how could i pass that value if i dont have component A nested in B. That's why im using behaviorSubject, or you mean using localStorage ?

Comment: `BehaviorSubject` only retains the last value. You can't use it to retain your set of values.

Comment: @Nacho, if you use array in a service, you can wrap it in subject; simply put, you can do whatever you want with array

Comment: @ABOS  I tried what you said but now i dont even get the value. You mean something like Subject<string[]> ?

Comment: @Nacho, it depends on how other parts of your code are going to use your data. In the simplest case, you can just put all image data in a service, and call `behaviorSubject.next(someService.imageData: ImageSate[])`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`BehaviorSubject` stores only current (last) value. Take a look at `ReplaySubject`, you can specify buffer to keep in it.

You can add buffer to an any stream to store values by using operator `shareReplay`.

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#replaysubject 
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html

Comment: If you want to get all images that you ever put in your subject on every subscribe, then create reply subject with with big buffer size. `imgStateSubject = new ReplaySubject<string>(1000);`

Comment: @Marksim Romanenko This is what i've been looking for, the only thing is that seems like if you assing a high value to the buffer it would cause memory leaks or replaySubject can handle it?